# How to Visualize Quick Sort Algo while it is arranging the elements in HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, quicksort

I have been working on this project for a while now and I would appreciate it if you guys could help me out.

The quick sort algorithm works but since it uses recursion I don't know how or where I should rearrange the HTML divs created.

I have tried rearranging the divs after each swap function is called but that does not seem to work any ideas on how I might solve this problem?

```
class Element{
    constructor(value , id){
        this.value = value;
        this.id = id;
    }

}


function generateElemenets(){
    for(let i = 0 ; i < 10; i++ ){
        
        let randomValue = generateRandomValue();

        values[i] = new Element(randomValue , i);
        const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.classList.add("element");
        newDiv.setAttribute("id", i);
        container.appendChild(newDiv);
        document.getElementById(i).style.height = `${randomValue}px`;

    

    }
    
}

function generateRandomValue(){
    let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 20);
    return x;
}


function quickSort(arr, start, end){
    
    if(start >= end){
        return;
    }

    let index = partition(arr,start, end);

    quickSort(arr, start, index-1);
    quickSort(arr, index + 1, end);
    return arr;

}

function partition(arr, start, end){

    let pivotIndex = start;

    let pivotValue = arr[end].value;

    for (let i = start; i < end ; i++){
        
            if(arr[i].value < pivotValue){
            swap(arr, i, pivotIndex);
            pivotIndex ++;

        }           
        
    }
        swap(arr,pivotIndex, end);

    

    return pivotIndex;

}




function swap(items, leftIndex, rightIndex){
    

    var temp = items[leftIndex];

    items[leftIndex] = items[rightIndex];

    items[rightIndex] = temp;
 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could:

- give the div elements an absolute position style, and set a transition effect when their left-coordinate changes.
- let the `swap` function return a promise that resolves when the transition effect is complete.
- Make the `quickSort`, `partition` functions asynchronous so they can `await` the swap promises to resolve

Here is an implementation:

```js
class Element{
    constructor(container, value, i) {
        this.value = value;
        
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("element");
        div.textContent = value;
        container.appendChild(div);
        div.style.height = `${value}px`;
        div.style.left = `${30*i}px`;
        div.style.top = `${120-value}px`;
        this.div = div;
    }
    move(i) {
        // Return promise that resolves when move is complete
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.div.addEventListener('transitionend', (e) => {
                this.div.classList.toggle('highlight', false);
                resolve();
            }, { once: true });
            this.div.classList.toggle('highlight', true);
            this.div.style.left = `${30*i}px`; // trigger transition effect
        });
    }
}

const generateRandomValue = () => Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 20);

function generateElements(container, length=10) {
    container.innerHTML = "";
    return Array.from({length}, (_, i) =>
        new Element(container, generateRandomValue(), i)
    );
}

async function quickSort(arr, start, end){
    if (start >= end) {
        return;
    }
    const index = await partition(arr, start, end);
    await quickSort(arr, start, index-1);
    await quickSort(arr, index + 1, end);
    return arr;
}

async function partition(arr, start, end) {
    let pivotIndex = start;
    const pivotValue = arr[end].value;
    for (let i = start; i < end ; i++) {
        if (arr[i].value < pivotValue) {
            await swap(arr, i, pivotIndex);
            pivotIndex++;
        }
    }
    await swap(arr,pivotIndex, end);
    return pivotIndex;
}

function swap(items, leftIndex, rightIndex) {
    if (leftIndex === rightIndex) return; // Nothing to do
    var temp = items[leftIndex];
    items[leftIndex] = items[rightIndex];
    items[rightIndex] = temp;
    return Promise.all([items[leftIndex].move(leftIndex),
                        items[rightIndex].move(rightIndex)]);
}

const elements = generateElements(document.querySelector("#container"));
setTimeout(() => 
    quickSort(elements, 0, elements.length - 1), 
1000);
```

```css
.element { 
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute; 
    transition: left 1s;
    background: white;
}

#container {
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.highlight {
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @trincot . How can you make this responsive? Using absolute positioning does not help with responsiveness ?

Comment: That is a broad question, and goes way beyond the question you asked. If you want to make a responsive solution, you'll have to define how you want it to behave: should bars have a dynamic width, spreading them across the available width? Should the heights become dynamic so that the largest bar takes the available height and the others adapt keeping the same ratio? What should happen when things get too small? Should the display split into two? Etc...etc. I suggest you work on this, and when you get stuck feel free to ask a new question focused on a particular issue with it.